# who communicates with the namenode in yarn?

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, hadoop-yarn

since the jobTracker in MapReduce1 is replaced by the Application Master and Resouce Manager in Yarn I wonder who is communication in Yarn with the namenode to find out where the data is stored in the different datanodes?
Is the Application Master doing so?

Comment: Are you asking which component decides each node Mappers are created on based on data locality? Or are you just wondering how the data is streamed to the Mapper?

Comment: Yes, I am asking which component decides which node Manager to process which data. In MapReduce 1 it was the jobTracker who was communicating to the namenode finding out where each data is located to allocate the map and reduce tasks to the TaskTracker. Who is doing it in yarn? There has to be a component communicating with the namenode to know where the data is located, or not?

Answer (score 0):

In YARN, the per-application `ApplicationMaster` is responsible for getting the information about the input splits from `Namenode`. Later when the task attempts are executed over the assigned nodes, the `YarnChild` fetches the respective splits from HDFS.